# Conditional where clause in firestore queries based on parameters

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

For example I have dynamic filter list for my list of product, from that filter list send https request to cloud function. then trying to set Multiple conditional where clauses from that request

Multiple conditional where clauses work in local firebase app, but not inside cloud function
 -- Update Code --

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import { Query } from "@google-cloud/firestore"; // update code
const cors = require("cors")({
  origin: true
});
admin.initializeApp();

const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
admin.firestore().settings(settings);

const database = admin.firestore();

export const getProduct = functions.https.onRequest(
  (request, response) => {
    return cors(request, response, async () => {
      try {
        let productRef = database.collection("product") as Query; // update code
        if(request.query.brand){
          productRef =productRef.where("brand", "==", request.query.brand)
        }
        if(request.query.lifeStyle){
          productRef =productRef.where("lifeStyle", "==", request.query.lifeStyle)
        }
        const productsQuery = await productRef.get();

        const products = productsQuery.docs.map(
          docRef => ({
            id: docRef.id,
            ...docRef.data()
          })
        );
        response.status(200).send(products);
      } catch (error) {
        response.status(500).send(error);
      }
  });
 }
);
```

after compile display error on console
[ts] Type 'Query' is not assignable to type 'CollectionReference'. [2322]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript is complaining that you're trying to change the type of `productRef`.  You are first assigning `productRef` with the result of a call to [`collection()`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.17.x/Firestore#collection).  From the linked API docs, you can see that it returns a [CollectionReference](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.17.x/CollectionReference.html) type object.  Then, you're trying to reassign `productRef` with the result of a call to [`where()`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.17.x/CollectionReference#where), which returns a different type [Query](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.17.x/Query.html).  TypeScript doesn't like you to change the types of variables.

Since a CollectionReference is a subclass of Query, you can instead just tell TypeScript that you want to deal with `productRef` as a Query the entire time:

```
let productRef = database.collection("product") as Query
```

Note the cast to Query here.

Comment: please can you tell me how to import Query to cloud function.

Comment: If you use VS Code, it will offer you the import automatically.

Comment: after update code VS code automatically update - import { Query } from "@google-cloud/firestore";

Comment: then I trying to deploy function error show in console Module '@google-cloud/firestore' is not listed as dependency in package.json , then I manual added @google-cloud/firestore to package.json , then run deploy function it successfully deploy. but after I send https request it not return any data or error